# customize leading and kerning in a text view in iPhone application

Tags: ios, core-text

I am using a UITextView in a iPhone application.I am using custom font.I want to set 32px line spacing in the text view also want to adjust kerning and leading between characters in text view.
Anyone knows about it?

Can the core text framework is helpful? If so, please explain how. How can Incustomize the line spacing in text view in iPhone application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Core Text, it has the feature to specify the leading-space of a paragraph, the first line head indent of a paragraph, the line-spacing, underline...

check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTParagraphStyleRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005114) here